# Trouble getting array values into dojo ItemFileReadStore

Tags: dojo

I need a `ItemFileReadStore` to fill `my dijit.form.FilteringSelect` widget with Dojo 1.6. My data is inside an Javascript object with the following structure:

```
[Object]
   |
   |--> [object]
   |--> [object]
           |
           |-->id:85
               name:someName
```

I've tried transforming this object to a JSON object which gives me something like this:

```
var dataValues = JSON.stringify(myObject);
// result = [{"id":85,"name":"someName"}]
```

I've tried using this JSON object to create the store in two different ways:

```
1.var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data:dataValues});


2.var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data: {
            identifier: 'id',
            items: dataValues }
});
```

Checking this document: 
`http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html#input-data-format` with examples I see that my Json object has the right form so I really don't know what is wrong but I keep getting errors in console.

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but you say you're using Dojo 1.6 and the reference guide you linked is Dojo 1.9. Might want to check the 1.6 documentation instead to see if it's any different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used dojos dojo/Store/Memory for my needs.
Here's the Reference: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/Memory.html

Have a look:

```
 var dataItems = {
                 identifier: 'name',
                 items:drawnGeometry // an Array
                };

        var store = new Memory({data:dataItems});
        GraphicStore = new ObjectStore({objectStore: store});
```

Regards, Miriam